# CSS framework for creating complex math expressions

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to show complex math expressions like this...

[image]

...without having to use images or javascript.

It seems like that there are HTML characters for most of the actual glyphs, so the challenge is to scale and stack them into the correct configuration. This seems doable, but not practical for a large number of expressions. My instinct is to put together a series of classes that combine to result in a "math CSS framework".

Before I open this pandora's box, I wonder if this is a problem that has already been solved. Google doesn't seem to think so, but maybe you know otherwise.

NOTE: I love snazzy HTML5 and jazzy CSS3 tricks as mucha as the next guy, but I need IE8+ :-(

Comment: MathML is the 'right tool', but of course Chrome has just dropped it. There's a plugin called MathPlayer for older IE. Firefox supports it natively. http://www.codecogs.com/latex/htmlequations.php and others do it using images from LaTeX.

Comment: I would use a backend framework for creating the images inline with your html

Comment: @programminginallston could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I just mean you will probably have more luck finding a PHP framework to automate formatting the unicode symbols or creating the images.  I know one of my professors wrote his own for linear algebra, but is still in the process of open sourcing it

Comment: There's also [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which is a cross-browser JavaScript library for displaying mathematical expressions.

Comment: @programminginallston How big of a task would you consider building a tool that could convert math to images? Is that a month task? A week? I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: @Emerson Why does it need to be a pure CSS solution when JavaScript frameworks (such as MathJax) can already do this?

Comment: @IamJohnGalt, There is a ton of code out there for rendering LaTeX, and it's trivial to write some JS that replaces inline LaTeX with the rendered version.

Comment: @programminginallston Cool. That sounds like a really cool idea. Can you suggest a library to use, possibly?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I guess it doesn't HAVE to be purse CSS, but my I'm looking for something with the smallest possible footprint, and my (possibly naive) sense was that this *should* be possible to do without javascript. But I also don't know MathJax, so I'll check it out and follow up shortly.

Comment: @IamJohnGalt sorry, I don't know of any personally, but I would go with the above client-side recommendation of MathJax

Comment: Could be helpfull: http://www.scientificpsychic.com/etc/square-root.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MathJax.

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/

Also this might help

http://www.myphysicslab.com/web_math.html.